# how to remove line breaks in a div when required field validtor visiblity =false (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, validation, line-breaks, requiredfieldvalidator

hi im have a very common problem but unable to find any answer
i have a div and there are validator controls in it. I have used br tag in ErrorMessage Text to show show each message in new line. My code is below

```
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" CssClass="lblMessageError"
        runat="server"  ErrorMessage="<br> User name field cannot be empty" ControlToValidate="txtUserName" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator> 
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ClientValidationFunction="ClientValidate" ControlToValidate="txtPassword" CssClass="lblMessageError" ErrorMessage="<br />The password must be more than 6 characters."></asp:CustomValidator>  
    <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" CssClass="lblMessageError" ControlToCompare="txtPassword" controlToValidate="txtRePassword" ErrorMessage="<br /> Password dont match with repassword"></asp:CompareValidator>  
</div>
```

when there is no error found then it show line breaks. all i want is when there is not error found line breaks are ommitted.

1) when all validators are hidden

'<%--line Break because no error found--%> 
  '<%--line Break because no error found--%> 
 
  ' <%--line Breakbecause no error found---%>

2) when one validator is visible and other and hidden

User name field cannot be empty
  ' <%--line Break because no error found--%> 
  ' <%--line Breakbecause no error found---%>
 
'<%-- ally my controls here--%>

and i also dont want to show all my errors in same line
any suggestions??

Comment: You could use [ValidatorCalloutExtenders](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ValidatorCallout/ValidatorCallout.aspx) which are looking much better as your approach or a [ValidationSummary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd5c6s6h%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `Display="Dynamic"` attribute to your validator, eg:

```
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" CssClass="lblMessageError"
    runat="server"  Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="<br> User name field cannot be empty" ControlToValidate="txtUserName" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: In addition to `Display="Dynamic"`, I had to also include `style="white-space: nowrap;"` in the parent element.